# Gridlineerror with Cartopy

Tags: projection, cartopy

I used this line thousend times:

```
    gl= ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True,
              linewidth=1, color='gray', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
```

for different plots. Now i wanted to replot some stuff and get the following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot label gridlines on a Orthographic plot.  Only PlateCarree and Mercator plots are currently supported.
```

Are there same change in the label routine?

Comment: What is the version of cartopy?  Try run `cartopy.__version__`

Comment: the Interessent point is... after reinstall my enviroment everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only reinstall my conda environment it finally works